# Can't define the problem in Unity properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically, my distant friend is making a game, and I decided to help him. I created Unity project, placed the assets, scenes and classes, all this stuff. When it came to SceneChanger.cs (not mine, my friend's class), it's always throwing an error, no matter was it him fixing an error or me. Here's a code and errors:

SceneChanger.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneChanger : MonoBehaviour {

private float timer = 2.0f; 

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
      timer -= Time.deltaTime; 
      if (timer <=0)
{
    static void ChangeScene(string LoadingGame)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (MainMenu);
    }
    static void Exit()
    {
        Application.Quit ();
    }
}
```

And here are the errors:

```
Assets\Scenes\SceneChanger (5).cs(23,2): error CS1513: } expected

Assets\Scripts\AssetExitVoid.cs(6,2): error CS1513: } expected

Assets\Scripts\EnemyAI.cs(23,1): error CS1529: A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations

Assets\Scripts\EnemyAI.cs(24,1): error CS1529: A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations

Assets\Scripts\EnemyAI.cs(21,1): error CS1028: Unexpected preprocessor directive

Assets\Scripts\EnemyAI.cs(22,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Assets\Scripts\ObjPoolShot.cs(58,52): error CS1026: ) expected

Assets\Scripts\ObjPoolShot.cs(58,57): error CS1002: ; expected

Assets\Scripts\ObjPoolShot.cs(58,57): error CS1513: } expected

Assets\Scripts\PlayerMoveActive.cs(2,1): error CS1529: A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(6,42): error CS1514: { expected

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(6,42): error CS1513: } expected

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(14,8): error CS1513: } expected

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(26,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(30,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(32,8): error CS1002: ; expected

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(34,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(34,10): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(35,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(35,16): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(35,21): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Assets\Scripts\SceneChanger.cs(35,25): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Thanks you beforehand!

Comment: Haven't you noticed that the code you post isn't neat?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are two missing close brackets

- one to close the if statement, and
- one to close the OnTriggerEnter function.

I would guess there is some missing code after the if statement as that is likely where both closing brackets should be.

Proper tabulation and consistent bracket placement can help you see the situation more clearly:

```
public class SceneChanger : MonoBehaviour 
{

    private float timer = 2.0f; 

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {   // <---- OnTriggerEnter opens

        timer -= Time.deltaTime; 

        if (timer <=0)
        {   // <--- if statement opens

            //looks like code missing code in here

     // } should go here - closes the if statement

 // } should go here - closes the function

    static void ChangeScene(string LoadingGame)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (MainMenu);
    }

    static void Exit()
    {
        Application.Quit ();
    }
}
```